# Connect a Label Printer via LAN Port directly to PC in Windows 11

Tags: networking, printer, windows-11, dhcp-server, label-printer

The problem:
I have 2 identical Label printers RP410. If I connect them via USB I can be lucky if both are correctly installed... but most of the time only one USB virtual printer port is visible (USB001) and i can only print on one printer(also random on which after each restart). I tried every combination of ports and hubs etc... nothing helps Windows 11 hates printers...

My possible solution 1:
Connect one of the printers directly to the PC via LAN port
The printer has a LAN Port and the PC also has a free LAN port.
The PC is connected to the Internet via Wlan and no other LAN connection is in range so I cant connect them to the router network

Questions:
How can i assign an IP address to the printer when i directly connect them to the PC?
The label printer does not have any controls...
Or is there a small free/cheap DHCP server tool?
Are there any other solutions?

Toaran

Comment: Can you connect a printer to the router ?

Comment: @harrymc, he wrote *"no other LAN connection is in range so I cant connect them to the router network"*

Comment: @YisroelTech: I know nothing about his setup and where is the router. Certainly there's a problem if it's at the neighbor's.

Comment: @Toaran: Are the other connection methods? You printers also support Rs232 serial and parallel.

Comment: my setup is wifi only in a storage building. the printers have to be at the different workstations otherwise you have to walk for a label 200m each time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to set IP settings, and anything else, on the printer using their [**Label Printer Tool**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ww5drAeuxIp2vACO_iB5HkP2wK01dT65/view?usp=sharing) (link from [here](https://www.rongtatech.com/category/downloads/4)):
[image]
(See Page 11 in the [***RP410\RP410Y\RP410C\RP411 Manual***](https://etexco.de/download/RP410_RP410Y_RP410C_RP411-Integration_Tool_Manual.pdf))

Two other options to consider:

- Doesn't the printer also support WiFi connection? (It's not on the product page, but Ethernet connection isn't there either and the aforementioned tool has a WiFi section)
- The product page lists Bluetooth as a connection option.

Comment: i had no idea this tool existed... I think that is what i need. i will test this asap.   These printers exist in many different versions... my 8 all have USB LAN and serial connection... but no wifi